# docker export container to other box

Tags: docker

I have docker desktop running on my laptop which is about to die, and jut got a new laptop and wanted to transfer that container to my new laptop.

the steps i took so far:

```
On Old Laptop
1. docker export test > /var/tmp/export_test.tar
2. docker save test > /var/tmp/save_test.tar

On new laptop
1. tried docker load < /var/tmp/save_test.tar
```

On when i open docker desktop, i don't see anything running. But when i do a docker image ls

I see the image in there, but how do i get to it run now?

Comment: I realize that's not exactly what you're asking, but have you considered pushing the image to a registry or temporarily run your own as described in https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/.

Comment: Did you try docker run?       Also you can push the image to docker hub

Comment: I finally got it to run, by doing the following docker run -d -p 8000:8000 test and it runs, but the problem now is, none of the data is in there any more

Comment: Is there a reason why the data and the mounts that were configured didn't stay in tact?

Comment: Mount are saved on the host, in your case the old computer. Also you didn't run the container with the volume at all